# Spotlight on Yosemite not launching Apps

Tags: macos, spotlight

My Yosemite spotlight does not start app anymore. I tend to use it for quickly starting up apps like Terminal, but now it just sort of hangs...

Any ideas to fix it?

Comment: Sadly after indexing is completed it still does not launch apps...

Answer (score 1):

It may be indexing or may have a corrupted index. Open Spotlight and check for an Indexing progress bar. If that is not present try going into the Spotlight PrefPane in System Preferences and forcing an index.